Dispose() inst working for JDialog when i try to close it
Im trying to dispose of JDialog but for some reason it doesnt work in any way i use it, im working on lottery in the first window i want to add created tickets and in jdialog i want to choose which numbers then make qr and when i press add i want my ticket to be added and jdialog should disapear but it stays
package cv8;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

import com.formdev.flatlaf.FlatDarkLaf;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class TicketDisplay {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField field;
    private JDialog dialog;
    
    cv2_cisla pridat = new cv2_cisla();

    public Ticket pridajNovy() {
        
        dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.setTitle("Vytvorte si tiket");
        dialog.setSize(750, 700);
        dialog.setModalityType(JDialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        Component[] components = pridat.getComponents();

        for (Component component : components) {
            dialog.getContentPane().add(component);
        }
        
        dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                Ticket ticket = pridat.addNewTicket();
                if (ticket != null) {
                    System.out.println(ticket.toString());
                }
            }
        });

        dialog.setVisible(true);
        
        while (dialog.isVisible()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
        Ticket ticket = pridat.addNewTicket();
        dialog.dispose();
        return ticket;
    }
    
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel( new FlatDarkLaf() );
                    TicketDisplay window = new TicketDisplay();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public TicketDisplay() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 700, 750);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("NOVE ZREBOVANIE");
        panel.add(btnNewButton_1);
        
        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("PRIDAJ");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                Ticket tk = pridajNovy();
                dialog.dispose();
                if(tk != null) {
                    System.out.println(tk.toString());
                }
            }
        });
        panel.add(btnNewButton);
        
        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel_1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("KENO 10");
        panel_1.add(lblNewLabel);
        
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(panel_2);
    }
}

package cv8;

import com.formdev.flatlaf.FlatDarkLaf;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class cv2_cisla extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JButton button;
    private JButton [] buttons;
    private JTextField cislo;
    private ArrayList <JTextField> cisla;
    private String finalNums;
    private int max = 10;
    private int count = 0;
    private Random r;
    private int rNums [];
    private ArrayList <Integer> nums = new ArrayList();
    private int suma = 0;
    private SpinnerNumberModel jsm;
    private JSpinner spiner;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel( new FlatDarkLaf() );
                    cv2_cisla frame = new cv2_cisla();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setSize(750, 700);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    
    CrunchifyQRCodeGenerator cqc = new CrunchifyQRCodeGenerator();
    
    BufferedImage bufferedImage;

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public cv2_cisla() {
        
        cisla = new ArrayList<>();
        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        JLabel labelQR = new JLabel("");
        
        jsm = new SpinnerNumberModel(1, 1, 10000, 5);
        
        spiner = new JSpinner(jsm);

        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 13, 0, 0));
        
        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel_1);
        
        buttons = new JButton [100];
        cisla = new ArrayList<>();
        panel_1.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));
        
        JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.add(panel_2);
        panel_2.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 10, 0, 0));
        
        JPanel panel_3 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.add(panel_3);
        panel_3.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 3, 0, 0));
        
        JButton buttonClear = new JButton("Clear");
        buttonClear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                panel_2.removeAll();
                for(int i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
                    if(buttons[i] != null) {
                        buttons[i].setEnabled(true);
                    }
                }
                count =0;
                panel_2.revalidate();
                panel_2.repaint();
                
            }
        });
        panel_3.add(buttonClear);
        
        JButton buttonRun = new JButton("Delete");
        buttonRun.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                panel_2.remove(cisla.remove(cisla.size()-1));
                count = -1;
                panel_2.revalidate();
                panel_2.repaint();
                
            }
        });
        panel_3.add(buttonRun);
        
        JButton buttonAdd = new JButton("Add");
        buttonAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dispose();
            }
            
        });
        
        JButton buttonOkay = new JButton("Okay");
        buttonOkay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                r = new Random();
                rNums = new int [cisla.size()];
                
                for(int i=0; i<cisla.size(); i++) {
                    rNums[i] = r.nextInt(0, 80);
                    System.out.println(rNums[i]);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < cisla.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(cisla.get(i).getText());
                    
                }
                
                contentPane.removeAll();
                JPanel panelQr = new JPanel();
                contentPane.add(panel_1);
                contentPane.add(panelQr);
                contentPane.add(panel_3);
                panelQr.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                contentPane.repaint();
                contentPane.revalidate();
                
                panel_3.removeAll();
                panel_3.add(buttonAdd);
                panel_3.add(spiner);
                
                bufferedImage = cqc.makeQr(getFinalNums());
                
                if(bufferedImage != null) {
                    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(bufferedImage); 
                    labelQR.setIcon(icon);
                    panelQr.add(labelQR);
                }
                else {
                    labelQR.setText("Something went wrong!");
                    panelQr.add(labelQR);
                }
            }
        });
        panel_3.add(buttonOkay);
        
        ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            
            if(count >= max) {
                return;
            }
            String num = ((JButton)e.getSource()).getText(); 
            cislo = new JTextField(num);
            panel_2.add(cislo);
            contentPane.revalidate();
            contentPane.repaint();
            ((Component) e.getSource()).setEnabled(false);
            cisla.add(cislo);
            nums.add(Integer.valueOf(cislo.getText()));
            System.out.println("cislo:" + nums.toString());
            count ++;
            }
        };
    
        for(int i=0; i<80; i++) {
            button = new JButton(String.valueOf(i+1));  
            button.addActionListener(al);
            buttons[i] = button;
            panel.add(buttons[i]);
        }
    }

    public String getFinalNums() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (JTextField textField : cisla) {
            sb.append(textField.getText());
            sb.append(" "); 
        }
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    
    public ArrayList <Integer> getNums() {
        return nums;
    }
    
    public Ticket addNewTicket() {
        
        Ticket ticket;
        suma = (int) spiner.getValue();
        
        if(suma == 0) {
            ticket = new Ticket(nums.size(), getNums());
        }else {
            ticket = new Ticket(suma, nums.size(), getNums());
        }
        return ticket;
        
    }
}       
        



You really need to provide a minimal reproducible example

The dialog is modal, which means the user needs to close the dialog. Typically this is done by clicking on a button in the dialog. In the ActionListener of that button you would add the dispose() statement to close the dialog. Or, if you want the user to click on the "X" at the top/right, then you need to set the setDefaultCloseOperation(...) method when you create the dialog. The "while loop" after showing the dialog is not required, since that code is not executed until the dialog is closed.

so is there any other component that I could use for this?

Use for what? A dialog is the proper component to use when you want to show a temporary window and ask the user for information or display information for the user. The user need to click on something to indicate they have entered all the information. So I don't understand the question.
